# What is Diffie-Hellman good for?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I understand the Diffie-Hellman process, but what I don't understand is: **what can we do with the shared secret?**

Say we're working $\bmod p$ with primitive root $r$. If Alice's private key is $\alpha$ and Bob's private key is $\beta$ then the shared secret will be $r^{\alpha \beta} \pmod p$. I can't see a way of making $r^{\alpha \beta} \pmod p$ be a number that either Alice or Bob chose beforehand, so they basically have a random number that no-one else knows.

But what good is that (effectively) random number $r^{\alpha \beta} \pmod p$?

What can they actually do with it?

Comment: If $3$rd person, D(evil) can listen channell between A(lice) and B(ob), then he knows both $r^{\alpha} (\bmod p)$ and $r^{\beta} (\bmod p)$, but he **cannot** compose shared key $r^{\alpha\beta} (\bmod p)$ in reasonably appropriate time, based on having info. A(lice) and B(ob) can do that easily $-$ both.

Comment: @Oleg567 I always thought it was E(ve).

Comment: Shared secret can be used then for symmetric-cryptography algorithms (to encrypt their further communication, for example) which is much more fast and comfortable than public-key algos.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, ... or E(nemy) ...

Comment: @Oleg567 but Eve is short for eavesdropper

Comment: @Oleg567 Yes, I understand that both Alice and Bob know a number that only they know but, as my question said, what is the point of that number? There is no way for Alice or Bob to make it so that $r^{\alpha\beta} \pmod p$ is a number they chose beforehand. Hence, both Alice and Bob have a random number that only they know. What use is that? What can they do with a random number?

Comment: @FlybyNight, they can use it as key for message encryption. Say, I want to email you some secret info, which I wish to encrypt using RAR archiver, and it would be great to use normal password, but our communication line is under listening. So, I cannot say you this pwd by email (and don't cnow other your coordinates like phone Nr etc). So, we use D-H trick sending "parts" of further shared key. And, in practice, use first 30 digits of the key $r^{\alpha\beta} (\bmod p)$ as the password, for example.

Comment: @Oleg567 That's interesting. So I can use it to set a password for a website, and the other person can access the website? But then what happens when the person uses the password to log-in to the website, can't the person listening hear the password and use it?

Comment: Such password would be random, and composed after $A-B$ "sub-keys" exchange. mostly as "session password", I guess...

Comment: the problem is that the "listener" knows only parts of the shared password, which can be "combined to complete password" without knowing $\alpha$ and/or $\beta$. (in reasonable time frames). Since it's problem to know/guess $a$ knowing $r$, $p$ and $r^{\alpha} (\bmod p)$.

Comment: @Oleg567 I totally understand the process. I know that Alice and Bob can share a secret that no-one else knows - I get this! This is not my question. I understand the Discreet Logarithm Problem, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By generating a shared random number, they can then use that random number to generate a shared key with which they can apply a symmetric encryption algorithm (as opposed to a public-key one like RSA, which is asymmetric, because it involves one key for encoding and a different key for decoding).

Symmetric encryption algorithms generally are *much* faster than public-key algorithms like RSA.  For any extended back-and-forth communication (as opposed to a one-off message), it's better to use a symmetric encryption algorithm.  The problem with symmetric encryption algorithms is that you need to agree on a secret key using an insecure channel (if you had a secure channel, you wouldn't need encryption to begin with).  That's the problem DH solves.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for -- thank you!

Comment: I would also point out that RSA can of course be used to exchange a key as well.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few fundamental problems in cryptography.  The problem that is most often discussed is "how easy is it to break the code".  However, we can devise a scheme where, as long as the communicators can agree on a random "key", it is literally impossible to break the code.  This scheme (at least, the simplest example of such a scheme) is known as a [one-time pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad).

With that in mind, the only challenge is to safely communicate this common, random key.  That is, we need to solve the [key-distribution problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_distribution).  Traditionally, encryption requires one side to create the key and secretly deliver it to the other side; however, if the enemy intercepts the key, they can decrypt the message.  The first thought one might have from there was to encrypt the key and then send it, but perhaps you can see how that brings us back to the same problem.

The Diffie-Helman key exchange (assuming it can't easily be reversed) solves the key-delivery problem by providing a way to generate and share a key in which an enemy can't simply decipher the code by intercepting a message.

So, what can we do with the shared secret?  Generate a one-time pad, for one.

---

Another solution to the key-distribution problem is [public key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography), which was also originally made by exploiting modular arithmetic and the difficulty of factorizing large numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've always been able to understand the point of RSA because it lets people send me messages that they have full control over, and not just generate a random number like DH does. Would you say that one application of DH would be to tell coders and decoders of the Enigma machines which pages to use on any given day? I'm guessing that RSA is *much* more useful than DH, then?

Comment: @FlybyNight: In principle, perhaps, but in practice, both RSA and DH are much slower than so-called symmetric or shared-key cryptosystems.  Thus, the public-key cryptosystems (whether DH or RSA) are meant only to exchange or to distribute (temporary) shared keys, and the shared keys are used for the actual bulk encryption.  Once that message is sent, the shared key is discarded for the sake of security, since new shared keys can be generated so cheaply.

Comment: @BrianTung thanks for replying. RSA is useful because it does the encryption for me. I can send you my public key, and you can write a message, turn it to numbers (space = 00, A=01, C=02, etc), and encrypt it using my public key. I can then decrypt it using my private key - done. A million people could send me messages that I can understand using the same public key. With DH, two people can share the same random number. Say we both know the number 137, and no-one else does, what can we do with 137 to transmit information - given that neither of us knew that 137 would come out when we started.

Comment: @BrianTung I don't think that DH qualifies as a "public-key cryptosystem".  It is a system for "public key-exchange", though.

Comment: @FlybyNight the answer to your first question is yes.  In other words, the shared random number is used to generate the key so that both parties know how to encrypt/decrypt without direct communication.  Also, I would say that by the points that Ted makes, this does not make RSA "more useful" than DH.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Yes, you're right.  I spoke sloppily.

Comment: @FlybyNight: A small number like 137 cannot do anything, you are right about that.  But the numbers exchanged by DH can be the size of a symmetric key (these are typically between 56 and 256 bits—large-ish but still much smaller than the keys used in public key systems), and then you use that shared secret to encrypt your messages.

Comment: @BrianTung Great, so we're finally getting to an answer. Your answer to my question seems to be that $r^{\alpha\beta} \pmod p$ can be used to encrypt messages. But how?!

Comment: @FlybyNight: If $p$ is a big enough number, it can be used as a key to an encryption system such as DES, 3DES, AES (to name some hoary old systems).  DES requires a $64$-bit key (of which $8$ bits are parity bits).  Thus, if $p > 2^{64}$, the result of the public-key operation can be used to share a DES key.  Other systems require larger keys ($2^{64}$ is no longer considered a large enough search space to avoid brute-force attack).  But most public-key moduli are large enough to permit this.

Comment: @BrianTung Excellent! Thank you.